# $\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d)=n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I want to solve $\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d)=n$ using Group theory.

Here, $\varphi(d)$ is Euler's totient function.

I think I should use $\Bbb Z_n$ and fundamental theorem of cyclic group.

Then I use $\varphi(d)$ as the number of generators of $\Bbb Z_d$

But I can't link this idea with the sum of all $ d|n $

Help me!

Comment: The order of a subgroup of the cyclic group is a divisor of $n$ and there is exactly one such group for each divisor.

Comment: Is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948620/n-positive-integer-then-n-sum-dn-phid-proof-rotmans-textbook?rq=1 not doing it for you?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you!! I understand it

Answer (score 1):

As usual, Gauss's proof is the best.  For each element of $C_n$, it generates a cyclic group of order $d$ dividing $n$.  And there are $\varphi(d)$ such elements for each such $d$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the fact that, if $n=\prod p_i^{\alpha_i}, \mathbb {Z_n}\simeq \prod \mathbb {Z_{p_i^{\alpha_i}}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The order of each element $k$ of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a divisor $d$ of $n$. Therefore,
$$
\left| \mathbb{Z}_n\right| = \sum_{d|n}\#\,\lbrace k \in \mathbb{Z}_n: k\text{ of order } d \rbrace
$$
An element $k$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ verifies $d \cdot k = 0$ if and only if $k$ belongs to the subgroup generated by $l = n/d$, which is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_d$. Then, $k$ is of order $d$ if and only if it is a generator of this subgroup. However, the number of generators of $\mathbb{Z}_d$ is $\varphi(d)$. Therefore,
$$
\#\,\lbrace k \in \mathbb{Z}_n: k\text{ of order } d \rbrace = \varphi(d)
$$
Now, it is enough to note the obvious, $\left| \mathbb{Z}_n\right| = n$.